# R How to find x if φ(x)=0.5?

Tags: r, normal-distribution

x is normal distribution with mean=3 and standard deviation=2. Given φ(x)=0.5, how to find x?

I know this is dnorm(x,3,2)=0.5 in R, but I'm not sure how to find x using R.

Comment: Something is wrong with your data. The density of a Normal peaks at the mean. However, `dnorm(3,3,2)=0.199`, so there is no `x` that will give you a larger value.

Comment: Careful, `pnorm` is the normal distribution cdf, not `dnorm` which is the pdf. You can solve `pnorm(something) = 0.5` via a root-finding function such as `uniroot`; this is a good exercise. However, it's also built-in via `qnorm`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you want to solve is `pnorm(x,3,2)=0.5`, rather than `dnorm(...)`, since the maximum of `dnorm(x,m,v)` is `1/(sqrt(2*pi)*v)`, mathematically, which is

```
> 1/(2*sqrt(2*pi))
[1] 0.1994711
```

if you have `m = 3` and `v = 2` in your specific case, and cannot reach `0.5`. Otherwise, we would say `dnorm(x,3,2) = 0.5` has no real solutions.

---

If that's true, then you should use `qnorm(0.5,3,2)` to solve `x`, which gives

```
> qnorm(0.5,3,2)
[1] 3
```

and we double check it

```
> pnorm(3,3,2)  
[1] 0.5
```